# Tensorflow does NOT utilize the memory from two GPUs in Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow Version 1.3.0
OS: Windows 10
GPUs: Nvidia Quadro M4000 * 2 with 8G GPU memory for each
GPU modes: one for WDDM, one for TCC

I tested the official codes at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/resnet/imagenet_main.py

I just add the GPU constraints in the main function as:

```
def main(unused_argv):
  os.environ['TF_ENABLE_WINOGRAD_NONFUSED'] = '1'

# For this line, visible_divice_list set to only "0" and "0, 1" can only support the same batch_size
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(visible_device_list='0, 1')) 

resnet_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
  model_fn=imagenet_model_fn, model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
  config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(session_config=config))

for cycle in range(FLAGS.train_steps // FLAGS.steps_per_eval):
tensors_to_log = {
    'learning_rate': 'learning_rate',
    'cross_entropy': 'cross_entropy',
    'train_accuracy': 'train_accuracy'
}

logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
    tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=100)

print('Starting a training cycle.')
resnet_classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda: input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN),
    steps=FLAGS.first_cycle_steps or FLAGS.steps_per_eval,
    hooks=[logging_hook])
FLAGS.first_cycle_steps = None

print('Starting to evaluate.')
eval_results = resnet_classifier.evaluate(
  input_fn=lambda: input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL))
print(eval_results)
```

In the training process, if I set the visible device list to "0, 1" or "0" only, both can run successfully with batch_size=48, but BOTH failed with batch_size=49! This indicates that the second GPU's memory is not utilized, as batch size could not be bigger when using two GPUs. I have use Nvidia-smi to confirm that only one or two GPUs are used in the above experiments.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way that I can use bigger batch_size when using two GPUs?
2. If the answer for Q1 is No in Windows, is there any way to do it in Linux? I am not familiar with Linux. In Linux, can I set all GPUs to TCC mode? Will the batch size be bigger when two GPUs are both in TCC mode?
   Thank you.

-------------Update------------

I have tried to distributed the data batch on two GPUs and there is NaN loss error now. Would there be any possible cause for this? It runs well before (using one GPU only). But now even I set the _DEVICE_LIST to one GPU only, it still produce the NaN loss error.

My modified codes are:

```
def imagenet_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  tf.summary.image('images', features, max_outputs=6)

  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    split_batch = tf.split(features, len(_DEVICE_LIST))
    split_labels = tf.split(labels, len(_DEVICE_LIST))

    all_predictions = {
      'classes': [],
      'probabilities': []
    }
    all_cross_entropy = []
    all_reg_loss = []

    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
      for dev_idx, (device, device_features, device_labels) in enumerate(zip(
        _DEVICE_LIST, split_batch, split_labels)):
        with tf.device(device):
          with tf.name_scope('device_%d' % dev_idx):
            logits = network(inputs=device_features,
                             is_training=(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN))

            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            all_predictions['classes'].append(tf.argmax(logits, axis=1))
            all_predictions['probabilities'].append(tf.nn.softmax(logits))

            if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            # Calculate loss, which includes softmax cross entropy and L2 regularization.
              cross_entropy = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
                logits=logits, onehot_labels=device_labels)
              reg_loss = FLAGS.weight_decay * tf.add_n(
                [tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in tf.trainable_variables()])

              all_cross_entropy.append(cross_entropy)
              all_reg_loss.append(reg_loss)


    all_predictions['classes'] = tf.reshape(all_predictions['classes'], [-1])
    all_predictions['probabilities'] = tf.reshape(
      all_predictions['probabilities'], [-1])

    total_cross_entropy = tf.add_n(all_cross_entropy)
    total_reg_loss = tf.add_n(all_reg_loss)
    total_loss = total_cross_entropy + total_reg_loss

    tf.identity(total_cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy')
    tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', total_cross_entropy)
    tf.summary.scalar('reg_loss', total_reg_loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('total_loss', total_loss)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
      global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
      boundaries = [
        int(batches_per_epoch * epoch) for epoch in [30, 60, 120, 150]]
      values = [
        _INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE * decay for decay in [1, 0.1, 0.01, 1e-3, 1e-4]]
      learning_rate = tf.train.piecewise_constant(
        tf.cast(global_step, tf.int32), boundaries, values)

      tf.identity(learning_rate, name='learning_rate')
      tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', learning_rate)

      optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(
        learning_rate=learning_rate,
        momentum=_MOMENTUM)

    # Batch norm requires update_ops to be added as a train_op dependency.
      update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
      with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(total_loss, global_step)
    else:
      train_op = None

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      predictions=all_predictions,
      loss=total_loss,
      train_op=train_op)
```

The error message is:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into F:\projects\DeepLearning\TensorFlow\Models\ImageNet\resnet_101_imagenet_augmented\temp\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:learning_rate = 0.003125, cross_entropy = 14.394
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 30.0782, step = 1
ERROR:tensorflow:Model diverged with loss = NaN.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 321, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "imagenet_main.py", line 310, in main
    hooks=[logging_hook])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 241, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 686, in _train_model
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 518, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 862, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 818, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 980, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 551, in after_run
    raise NanLossDuringTrainingError
tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```